# I want a function to ssh into a server and then run a list of commands

Tags: bash, ssh, function

What I would like to do is:

```
f(){
 ssh myserver &&
 ls &&
 echo 'it works!'
}
```

However, when I run this function. Only the ssh is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the list of commands directly after  `ssh myserver`:

```
ssh myserver 'ls && echo it works'
```

Comment: Is there a way I can pass variables? Such as: ´path=`pwd` && ssh myserver 'cd ${path} && ls'´

Comment: `ssh myserver "cd $(pwd) && ls"`

Comment: This for some reason did not work..., It uses the pwd after I have connected but I want it to use the pwd from where I ran the function.

Comment: Make sure you use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To use a function or complex script via ssh, it's easier to copy the script to the host instead of trying to execute it as one ssh command, because it's tricky to handle all the escapes.

```
scp myscipt.sh host:
ssh host "./myscript.sh"
```

or

```
cat myScript.sh | ssh host "cat - > myScript.sh; . ./myScript.sh; rm myScript.sh"
```